# How do I install USB Blaster driver on Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu

I'm using a virtual box with Lubuntu 20.04 and I need to install the USB Blaster drivers does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: It may help you get more helpful suggestions if you tell us what *USB Blaster drivers* actually are.

Comment: so USB Blaster is a driver for the app Quartus made by intel. It connects the applicatication to a board to solve some logical functions

Comment: If I remember you correctly, you do not need any drivers. It has FTDI232 inside, so will be auto-recognized by kernel. If unsure - please connect blaster to the computer and execute `lsusb -t` , add the output to question.

Comment: @N0rbert Yes, assuming the device is recognized by the guest OS. It depends on Virtualbox to pass the serial port.